# Connecting Angular front end to lotus notes using Domino Data Service

Tags: angular, rest, lotus-domino

I am trying to GET Lotus Notes/Domino database view data from Angular application running on NodeJS using Domino Data Service. I have setup Website Document and internet Site on my domino server and enabled Data in server configuration. My angular application and domino database are running on different servers.

When I try to GET data from my local using "http:{host}/{database}/api/data/collections/unid/{unid}", I am able to get the data in JSON format. But when I try to GET the same data from my angular application, I am getting error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://{host}/{database}/api/data/collections/unid/{unid}' from origin 'https://localhost:9443' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

My Angular application is running on port 9443.

I have searched for this this error and tried everything I got, but no luck yet. I have added all the headers in domino server internet site document and also enabled all the REST methods (GET, PUT, DELETE.. etc). But still getting the same error.

Here is the code I am using,

```
    getDoc() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.get(url, options).subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      error => console.error(error),
      () => { }
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your Angular application is loaded from a different server, the Domino REST API request violates the browser's Same Origin policy. You should read about the Same Origin policy and Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). There are lots of good tutorials on the Internet.

But the summary is you have two options:

1. Move your Angular application to the Domino server. Like most HTTP servers, Domino can easily host static resources like HTML, CSS and JavaScript files. If you use this approach, your Angular scripts will make REST API requests to the same origin and the CORS error will go away.
2. Configure Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on the Domino server. If you are using Domino 10.0.1 FP2, you can use the new [CORS filter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_10.0.1/admin/conf_cors.html). It is more difficult for previous versions of Domino. I believe you can use web site rules to simulate CORS, but you'll have to search for help on that.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Unfortunately I can not move angular application to my domino server due to some limitations. I have Domino 9.0.2 and I tried to configure CORS on that, but that seems to be not working as well.. :(. Is there any other way available for Domino 9?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take a look at the AppDev Pack, which allows you to use node.js to access Domino data directly.
You can read more here:
https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/homepage.html
https://turtleblog.info/2018/11/04/deploying-the-appdev-pack-an-admins-guide/
https://turtleblog.info/2018/11/04/using-node-js-to-access-domino/

Comment: Thanks Karl. Unfortunately I have Domino 9 installed and AppDev Pack seems to be only supported by Domino 10. Is there anything available for Domino 9?

Comment: No, you need to use Domino 10 for AppDev Pack. Is there a reason why you won't update from a version released in 2013? Domino 10 has been out for almost a year now, and version 11 is coming in the end of the year...
An alternative would be to write your own REST API, then you can perform JSONP-calls, which would solve the CORS issue.